# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "carrinho" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.3

I'm using rails 4, ruby 2.3 and have a problem. How solve this error?

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "carrinho" does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT  "carrinho".* FROM "carrinho" WHERE "carrinho"."id" I...
>                                     ^ : SELECT  "carrinho".* FROM "carrinho" WHERE "carrinho"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1

My model is carrinho.rb
My controller is carrinhos_controller.rb
My views is carrinhos
My migration is 20160204181641_create_carrinhos.rb

And in inflections have:

> ```
>   inflect.plural "carrinhos", "carrinhos"
>   inflect.plural "carrinho", "carrinhos"
>   inflect.singular "carrinhos", "carrinho"
>   inflect.singular "carrinho", "carrinho"
>   inflect.irregular 'carrinho', 'carrinhos'
> ```

Make A week that I try to solve this problem. Please, help-me!!

Comment: After creating the migration, did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Why not just use english for you tables, classes and identifiers? https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming.

Comment: It was not my fault, the project was already in Portuguese

Comment: it seems taht you have too many plural/singular conversions... why just dont use: `inflect.irregular 'carrinho', 'carrinhos'`? yes, and run migration first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this, I just chanced position of inflect.irregular "carrinho", "carrinhos" to the beginning, and worked!
I didn't know that the order influences, but now I don't mistake more. I hope it helped all.